# Determine where browser is going to download files, excel and VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, csv

First I admit this should be really easy but i'm just not seeing the answer.

I'm getting info from a web site that I do not control. The web site, after selecting some options on the page, will download a CSV file. I've got everything working up to the download.

```
dim IE as InternetExplorer

dim doc as HTMLDoc

' setup the page

' get page to generate CSV

' now i need to go find the file and read it in

' Where is it?
```

I know that i can create a dialog box and ask the user to navigate to the file. However i'm dealing with people who are not that computer literate and asking them to find a file doesn't work that well.

I know that %homedir %homepath \downloads should be right but i've forgotten how to create a path based on those variables. Plus i'm not positive that is always correct so i want a way to ask the browser where it's going to store the file.

Comment: Look up [`Enivron$()` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg264486(v=office.14).aspx)

Comment: Do you want to to save the document in a specific location, or just bring up the SaveAs dialog in the correct folder?

Comment: Environ gives me values, thanks for pointing me there. What is the set that creates the download location?

Comment: @jmdon, i want to figure out WHERE the browser is saving the file. No dialog box pops up, just click and it appears in the download folder. What i want to do is read from the download folder the downloaded file. I want to make sure i'm looking in the right folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Environ("HOMEDRIVE")& Environ("HOMEPATH") & "\Downloads"
```

This works for me on Windows 7. You may need to write something to check the Windows version and change the format accordingly.

This is reliant on the download being saved in the default Downloads folder for that user.

Comment: working in win 8 also, so hopefully will catch all of the cases users will be in. Thanks lots, i just couldn't remember the environ function. It's been too long since i've been coding :)

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is not correct.

It will only be correct if the default Download location has not been changed in IE(7,9,11)->Settings->View Downloads->Options->Default Download Location.

The accepted answer doesn't even provide the Windows download location or
the Browser Download location (as requested in the topic heading.)

Also HomeDrive and the Users Home Drive may not be the same thing

As you can see from the output below the Windows Download folder is different from the IE Download Folder and the home drive is different
from the users home drive (profile):

**Pre-define this function first:**

```
    Public Function RegKeyRead(s_RegKey As String) As String
      Dim myWS As Object
        On Error Resume Next
        Set myWS = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")   'access Windows scripting
        RegKeyRead = myWS.RegRead(s_RegKey)        'read key from registry
    End Function
```

**Test in VBA Immediate (Ctrl + G)**

> ```
>     print Environ("HomeDrive")    
>     'C:
> ```

> ```
>     print Environ("UserProfile")   
>     'C:\Users\UserName
> ```

> ```
>     print RegKeyRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Default Download Directory")
>    'D:\TmpStorage\IEDownLoads
> ```

> ```
>     print RegKeyRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}")
>     '%UserProfile%\Downloads
> ```

Comment: Thanks Walter. Your answer is definitely more accurate. As you said, if the default download folder ewas changed, the accepted answer doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

This is my version :

```
    ' Recherche le répertoire de téléchargement pour IE. Si pas trouvée : on récupère la clée "User Shell Folders"
    With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        On Error GoTo erreur_registre
        CheminTelecharge = .RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Default Download Directory")
        GoTo suite_registre

erreur_registre:
        CheminTelecharge = .RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders\{374DE290-123F-4565-9164-39C4925E467B}")

suite_registre:
        CheminTelecharge = Replace(CheminTelecharge, "%USERPROFILE%", Environ("userprofile"))
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
```